# Pandas replace the last three characters in one column with another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in a python pandas data frame

| id | price | price_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 22,23 | .23 |
| b | 230,450,330.55 | .55 |
| c | 100,55 | .55 |

I wish to replace the last three digits in column two with the values of the third column. More broadly this is to try and normalize a bunch of prices based on how different countries use the comma and the decimal point. I come from an R background so this is pretty straight forward in that but i am coming a bit stuck in python.

My code at the moment looks something like below

```
# If the 'price' field has 
if mydf['price'].str[-3:].str.count(',').sum() >= 1 == True:
  mydf['price_end'] = mydf['price_end'].str[-3:].str.replace(",", ".")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask and then set only filtered rows by mask with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for specified columnsnames for replace:

```
mask =  mydf['price'].str[-3:].str.contains(',')
s = mydf.loc[mask, 'price_end']
mydf.loc[mask, 'price_end'] = s.str[:-3] + s.str[-3:].str.replace(",", ".")
```

If need repalce last 3 values by another column with mask (e.g. here if there is `,`):

```
print (mydf)
  id           price price_end
0  a           22,23       .73
1  b  230,450,330.55       .85
2  c          100,55       .95

mask =  mydf['price'].str[-3:].str.contains(',')
mydf.loc[mask, 'price'] = mydf.loc[mask, 'price'].str[:-3] + mydf['price_end'].str[-3:]
print (mydf)
  id           price price_end
0  a           22.73       .73
1  b  230,450,330.55       .85
2  c          100.95       .95
```